# Проблема с функциями с библиотекой openai, python

Tags: python, telebot

вот сам код:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['bing'])
def chat(message: telebot.types.Message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user_query = message.text[len('/bing') + 1:]
 
        if user_query == "":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ваш запрос!")
            return
 
        if user_id in chat_storage:
            chat_history = chat_storage[user_id]
        else:
            chat_history = []
 
        user_nickname = message.from_user.username
        functions_2 = [
            {
                "name": "internet_search",
                "description": "Search With Bing",
                "parameters": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "prompt": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "Bing description",
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["prompt"],
                },
            }
        ]
 
        functions = [
            {
                "name": "block_chat",
                "description": "Block the chat with user if you were offended, one-way function",
                "parameters": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {},
                    "required": [],
                },
            }
        ]
 
        chat_history.append({"role": "user", "content": f"{user_query} ({user_nickname})"})
 
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '...')
 
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            functions=functions,
            functions_2=functions_2,
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": """You are Bing, chat mode of Microsoft Bing.
                You identify as Microsoft Bing, not an assistant.
                You use artificial intelligence to understand questions.
                Use emoji: 
                lang_code="user language"
                if you are offended - block chat"""},
                *chat_history
            ],
            temperature=0
        )
        response_message = response['choices'][0]['message']
        if response_message.get("function_call"):
            available_functions = {
                "block_chat": json_function,
            }
            available_functions_2 = {
                "internet_search": internet_function,
            }
 
            function_name = response_message["function_call"]["name"]
            function_to_call = available_functions[function_name]
            function_args = json.loads(response_message["function_call"]["arguments"])
            function_response = function_to_call(user_id)
            if function_name == "block_chat":
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Возможно, пришло время сменить тему. Начнем сначала.")
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, function_response)
            pass
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, msg.message_id)
            return
            function_name_2 = response_message["function_call"]["name"]
            function_to_call_2 = available_functions_2[function_name_2]
            function_args_2 = json.loads(response_message["function_call"]["arguments"])
            function_response_2 = json_function(function_args_2["prompt"], user_id)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, function_response_2)
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, msg.message_id)
            return
        chat_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response['choices'][0]['message']['content']})
 
        chat_storage[user_id] = chat_history
 
        bot.edit_message_text(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'], message.chat.id, msg.message_id)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ошибка в Bing: {e}")
 
def internet_function(prompt):
    with DDGS() as ddgs:
        results = [r["body"] for r in ddgs.text(prompt, max_results=5)]
        print(results)
```

**Первые функции еле как на костылях сделал, вторые просто никак не получаются, выдаёт ошибку: Ошибка в Bing: Unrecognized request argument supplied: functions_2.**